# get latest filename after iterating through filenames in a folder in python

Tags: python

I have a list of folders. I iterate through each folder and read the filenames and extract the date from them which is in the format 21Mar15. Next I convert the the date to 2015-03 as string or object. I want to find out which is the latest file or rather get the latest date from each folder into a variable. I am badly stuck. Please help.
My code goes like this:

```
folders = []
folders = ftp.nlst() 
folders = map(str, folders) 
folders.sort() 
new_batches = [folder for folder in folders] 
#gets a list of folders in the ftp 
def folder_num(folder): 
    ftp.cwd(folder) 
    x=[] 
    x=ftp.nlst() 
    return x 
folder_list = len(folder) 
for batches in new_batches:
    y=folder_num(batches)
    if batches == "ABCD":

        for b in y:
            if (len(b)== 19):
                #print b[8:15]
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(b[8:15], '%d%b%y').date().strftime('%Y-%m')
                print b + " "+ date
            else:
                #print b[9:16]
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(b[9:16], '%d%b%y').date().strftime('%Y-%m')
                print b +" " + date
        ftp.cwd("//")
    elif batches == "EFGH":     
        for b in y:
            if (len(b)== 19):
                #print b[8:15]
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(b[8:15], '%d%b%y').date().strftime('%Y-%m')
                print b +" " + date
            else:
                #print b[19:26]
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(b[19:26], '%d%b%y').date().strftime('%Y-%m')
                print b +" " + date
        ftp.cwd("//")
```

The output is as follows:

```
ABCD
abcd23Mar15 2015-03
abcd130Apr15 2015-04
EFGH
efgc12Apr15 2015-04
efgh115Feb15 2015-02
```

---

I need to have

```
var1_for_ABCD = 2015-04
var2_for_EFGH = 2015-04
```

Or, Please help me to calculate the latest date, for each folder.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide the shortest *complete* program that demonstrates your question. In particular, what does `folder_num()` do?

Comment: Can't you just save a `date` variable when you iterate through each folder, and see if it is bigger than the previous or not?

Comment: shortest complete program is as follows:

#after I take connection to my FTP site
folders = ftp.nlst()
folders = map(str, folders)
folders.sort()
new_batches = [folder for folder in folders]
#gets a list of folders in the ftp
def folder_num(folder):
 ftp.cwd(folder)
 x=[]
 x=ftp.nlst()
 return x
folder_list = len(folder)
# List to hold new batches from last read 

Then the previous mentioned code follows till end.

#I am not able to take the extracted dates in a single list per folder to evaluate the latest date using max()

Comment: Please help me to calculate the latest date out of the extracted dates.

Answer (score 2):

Both the `datetime` objects you're creating temporarily, and the `YYYY-MM` strings you're building from them are comparable with `<`. You can find the maximum simply by comparing each date with the maximum that you've seen so far:

```
    max_date = ""
    for b in y:
        if (len(b)== 19):
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(b[8:15], '%d%b%y').date().strftime('%Y-%m')
            if data > max_date:
                max_date = date
        else:
            #print b[9:16]
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(b[9:16], '%d%b%y').date().strftime('%Y-%m')
            if data > max_date:
                max_date = date

    # do something here with max_date?
```